# Are psilocybin mushrooms permitted/prohibited/advocated in Jewish law or tradition?

Tags: halacha, mushrooms, intoxication

What does Jewish law or tradition have to say about magic mushrooms? Or in general, about any hallucinogen.

Is it forbidden to consume psilocybin mushrooms or other hallucinogens? Is it advocated? Why?

It seems like the large psychedelic community of Israel approves. Do they have any authority or tradition to support them?

Comment: See this: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10609/1569

Comment: In the written torah text or in the tradition developed through the written torah, the oral law and the authoritative statements of the sages and rabbis? http://www.chabad.org/blogs/blog_cdo/aid/1171699/jewish/The-Problem-With-Drugs.htm related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/may-one-consume-peyote

Comment: Hi Benny welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here. Hope to see you around.

Comment: Benny, I second the welcome. If you have any reason to think other drugs might be different from [marijuana](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10609), please [edit them into the question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/26517/edit) to distinguish it from the preexisting one.

Comment: If not what - prohibited or advocated?

Comment: @msh210, I'm ok with it as-is insofar as it is not a duplicate of the marijuana question. This one specifies hallucinogenic drugs, which, if I'm not mistaken (though I might be), does not include marijuana. In addition, marijuana is usually smoked, which may carry added risk.

Comment: Benny, feel free to revert if you disapprove of my changes.

Comment: @msh210, having said that, I believe it's a duplicate of this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16341/5

Comment: @SethJ for the record, as Kordovero notes, cannabis is a (very weak) hallucinogen.

Comment: @yoel, I'll have to trust Kordovero's expertise on the matter. ;-)

Comment: @SethJ also, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_(drug)#Psychoactive_classification) and probably, from there, relevant scientific studies.  I am reticent to research this subject further while at work. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Even if there is a "psychedelic community" in Israel that approves of "magic mushrooms," that is not an indication that Judaism approves of it. In nearly every country there is a small group of people obsessed with psychedelic drugs, and they pretty much approve of them all. Since they are ideologues, they have no credibility. Don't listen to them.

These mushrooms were not known to people outside of Mexico/Central America until very recent times. So the Torah says nothing about it. But major gedolim such as R' Moshe Feinstein have said not to use marijuana (which is a mild hallucinogen so it's also a psychedelic). And there is no respected Orthodox rabbi I'm aware of who has approved of any illegal drug use.

Common sense, scientific evidence and common experience also should keep us from using this drug. As with any psychedelic drug, there are grave risks of severe, long-lasting psychological problems, such as permanent perceptual changes ("hallucinogen persisting perception disorder" or HPPD), panic attacks, and anxiety problems. There is also the danger that one will have experiences which one thinks are genuine spiritual experiences but in fact are misleading or dangerous. For this reason, some kabbalists (such as Rabbi Ariel bar Tzadok) do not take anyone as a student who has used psychedelic drugs.

The Torah requires us to guard our health. That includes our mental health, of course. So we should avoid all illegal drugs, and psychedelic drugs in particular, like the plague.

If you want an interesting or transcendental experience, Judaism provides traditional means for doing so: prayer, meditation, fasting, wine, dancing, music, etc. These are safe in moderation. There's no need to experiment with dangerous drugs.

Comment: Aside from the fact that there is no pharmocological evidence to suggest that psilocybin (which are non-toxic) are "dangerous drugs", it's simply untrue to claim that psychotropic plants were never native to the Ancient Near East. We have evidence for a range of different hallucinogenic plants, used in medicine and ritual, from Mespotomia to Egypt - including certain fungi. While they appear to be absent from Tanakh, they may be alluded to in the "apocryphal" literature. Consider 4 Ezra 9:26ff, where Ezra eats flowers and then has a vision of the heavenly Jerusalem.

Comment: While it may not be, pharmacologically speaking, a poison, there is plenty of research confirming psilocybin's dangerousness. Numerous studies show serious psychiatric consequences from this substance, ranging from HPPD to full-blown psychosis. A recent British study found that about a quarter of psilocybin users got panic attacks from using it. van Amsterdam J, Opperhuizen A, van den Brink W. (2011). "Harm potential of magic mushroom use: a review". Regulatory Toxicology and Pharmacology 59 (3): 423–9.

Comment: There may be evidence that various cultures have used hallucinogenic plants, but the evidence for use among Jews is either non-existent or extremely speculative (as with the 4 Ezra reference.)

Comment: Legality shouldn't interfere. The law does not work along with Jewish law. Correct? It is know that if correctly consumed, magic mushrooms are safe and natural hallucinogens. Health risks shouldn't be a problem if consumed correctly.

Comment: Benny, that is not correct. Jewish law requires us to follow the law of the land. You are also incorrect about safety. There is no such thing as consuming it correctly. People take "normal" doses under normal conditions all the time (even with the best of idealistic or "spiritual" intentions) and end up with serious negative side effects such as panic attacks or HPPD. This happens with every psychedelic (whether "natural" or synthetic). This is documented by numerous studies, and is common knowledge among sufferers of drug-induced disorders (see their message boards, etc.)

Comment: @Benny I think the error you are making with regards to the law of the land is that there are those in Israel who hold that the zionist government is inherently invalid and *its* laws have no bearing.  I think you will be hard pressed to find traditionally observant Jews in chutz laretz who hold likewise, although the extent to which dina d'malchuta dina applies is certainly debatable, and many would indeed say it does not apply to drug use.

Comment: Jewish law makes no requirements on us whatsoever to follow the law of the land, though this might be another topic altogether. The oft-used "דינא דמלכותא דינא" clause refers to taxation. Alcohol didn't become halakhically prohibited by virtue of prohibition, and nor do psilocybin by virtue of the legislation that prevents people purchasing *them*. One has a civil, not an halakhic, obligation to observe the laws of the state in which one lives, which is why one faces civil punishments and never halakhic ones for infringing them.

Comment: The foregoing is not an argument in favour of fungi, but it needed to be said. @Kordovero is correct in saying that there's no evidence of Jews using such drugs in the ancient world, but incorrect to suggest that this is necessarily an argument against them. There is no evidence of Jews using tobacco in the ancient world either, yet despite insurmountable evidence of its addictiveness and toxicology, there was a long period when it was encouraged in Jewish circles, and many religious Jews today continue to use it.

Comment: What if at the instance of the _crime_, the individual is to consume the substance in a land which permits the consumption. As I see it, it seems as it's not covered by Jewish law. I also don't believe it falls under the category of health harms. You could harm yourself with anything, so this shouldn't be different. In generalization, if a Jew safely consumes the substance, what would be his results? For what else may the individual be punished for?

Comment: Why is it that some Jewish law is created for the sake of being, and is punished upon if you make the wrong choice? This is for the purpose of morals. And on the side of that, God placed these natural elements in his soil and did not even clearly define their _negative_ use. Positive use was found. Topics like this allow me to really question my faith. Aside from my faith, I believe that we, as G-d's creations should not be restricted from natural elements. We should fully make use of all that is provided for us, and complete our lives the positive way we wish, to accomplishment.

Comment: @ShimonbM it's a machlokes how much dina dimalchusa dina covers, but obviously all would agree that it cannot annul a positive mitzvah, such as arba kosos for example.

Comment: @Benny if you're questioning your faith over being able to do psychedelic drugs, I strongly recommend you take it up with your rabbi.  If you prefer not to take it directly to your own rabbi, might I humbly suggest Rabbi Lazer Brody of Ashdod (rabbi_lazer@yahoo.com), who, being very involved in outreach in Israel, is no stranger to the large Israeli psychedelic community and can surely offer you fair and balanced guidance.

Comment: Thanks Yoel -- good rabbi recommendation. As Yoel suggests, most authorities hold that dina dimalchusa dina is much broader than just paying taxes.

Comment: Benny, certainly, Hashem created everything in this world for a reason, for us to learn something from it or use it in some way. But that doesn't mean that Hashem inteded us to use shrooms or recreational or "spiritual" purposes. For example, why did Hashem create coca? Not so that people could become cocaine addicts. Perhaps it was for the legitimate medical applications that have been found for cocaine. As for "shrooms," perhaps some medical applications will be discovered one day? Or perhaps He intended them to be used only by Indians in ceremonies handed down from generation to generation?

Comment: Shimon, tobacco is a bad example. Jews had been using it for centuries until its long-term health effects were documented in epidemiological research. Currently, the vast majority of rabbinic authorities ban its use. In contrast, soon after psilocybin was introduced to Westerners, it was scientifically documented, and became common knowledge, that users frequently develop panic attacks or other psychiatric problems. What could be worse than panic attacks and such? What could be more precious and essential to our happiness and our avodas Hashem than peace of mind and tranquility?

Comment: @Kordovero I've read about the drugs causing panic attacks, but I've also read that psychedelics are experimentally being used to treat PTSD and terminal disease patients.  How can this be?

Comment: "Since they are ideologues, they have no credibility. Don't listen to them." Wow. Sounds like a nun warning about the dangers of sex.  ...and, no, I'm not part of this country's "small group".

Comment: Gary, I haven't examined the research about PTSD in detail, but I think it goes without saying that the fact there is such research does not mean that recreational use is a good idea. Moreover, I know that at least some of this research is funded by or carried out by people who are biased in favor of psychedelics (presumably from their own experimentation) and want to convince people that psychedelics are good. So some skepticism toward this research would be warranted.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that even though there are some studies, this is a very new field, and it's possible that with time and properly-controlled studies, people will find that these drugs either have no therapeutic effect, or have such frequent and serious side effects that it's not worth it to use it as a treatment. Even if some therapeutic effect is consistently shown, it may be that only very doses much smaller than recreational users use, or conditions much different from those in which recreational users use the drug, allow the therapeutic effects to occur.

Comment: As for the "ideologues" comment, I know about them because I read their articles and books when I was in college. It's easy for otherwise intelligent people to read their stuff, become persuaded that doing these drugs is great and the most important thing in the world ("it will blow your mind and make you one with the universe!"), and end up seriously messing up their minds and psyches. Since they are passionate about recruiting people, I think passionately critiquing them and warning people to stay away from them is warranted. See Tehillim 1:1 (don't listen to the council of the wicked).

Comment: Kordovero, of course "recreational" use, where the user has no respect for the power of the substance, is a bad idea.  However, these substances ARE here for a reason.  The biological forms have been used for thousands of years--they obviously need to be taken in a positive clinical or ritual environment. Before LSD hit "the streets" and subsequently was banned, there was plenty of valid research going on.  Read some of it...and remember - Timothy Leary(archetypical ideologue) died early but Albert Hoffman lived until 102.

Comment: Gary: Yes, everything is here for a reason, but that doesn't necessarily mean we know what that reason is. Unfortunately, I think people get the idea that these substances can only be harmful if one does them for the wrong reasons. But from people I know, I can tell you that serious negative effects can occur even when one has the best motivations (spiritual growth, for example). I have even seen reports from indigenous peoples indicating that some people who have used these drugs ritually end up "going crazy" from them. As for the research, some may be valid, but skepticism is warranted.

Answer (score 5):

See [Aryeh Kaplan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Kaplan) in [Meditation and Kabbalah](http://nleresources.com/kiruv-and-chinuch/online-books/chassidus-and-kabbalah/meditation-and-kabbalah/), where he mentions that R' Chaim Vital may have used psychedelic grasses. The gemara in Shabbos, I believe talks about "peiros ginosar" who's flavor is seemingly psychedelic. Although I asked a certain R' Sokol, and was told that the gemara in a different location says "once the beis hamikdash was destroyed, the taste of fruits was annulled." He said this means there is no longer fruit that raises consciousness, it only comes from herbs and grasses. The mishkan was made almost entirely of acacia or mimosa wood, both of the worlds most potent hallucinogens. The anointing oil contained "kaneh bosom" which R' Aryeh Kaplan identifies as cannabis. The Holy Zohar says that, "There is no grass or herb that grows in which G-d's wisdom
is not greatly manifested and which cannot exert great influence in heaven" and "If men
but knew the wisdom of all the Holy One, blessed be He, has planted in the earth, and
the power of all that is to be found in the world, they would proclaim the power of their Lrd in His great wisdom" (Zoh. II, 80B).

Also see http://lucidconsciousness.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/biblical_entheogens.pdf
and http://koshertorah.com/PDF/Drug%20Use.pdf

I have heard many things from many rabbis. The general consensus seems to be that we have a path to follow and it is the way we walk. There are no shortcuts, there is no running before you walk. But this is the messianic age. Who knows what will come to be. I remember hearing from one rabbi that the gemara says "When the temple was destroyed, prophecy was given to the insane, children, and dogs" If you take a chemical that makes you  "insane" maybe you can get prophecy, who knows. It is supposed to return when Moshiach gets here.

Comment: Asher Burrows, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for posting this answer! You could make it even more valuable by adding links or bibliographic information for all books mentioned, breaking it up into paragraphs, and separating speculation from ideas you have sources for (or even removing the former). I hope you'll look around the site and find other top-quality stuff, perhaps including our 13 other questions about [tag:inebriation].

Comment: "identifies" is a strong word http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=2&CHAPTER=30#C1800

Answer (score 3):

The response of Rabbi Moshe Feinstein in Igrot Moshe concerning the prohibition of marijuana consumption would also apply to all hallucinogenics. He prohibited intoxication that was to such an extent that it made proper Torah study impossible. Clearly, Purim would be an exception in regard to wine, but as a general practice, he found that level of intoxication to be prohibited.

Although there are many voices saying the usage of hallucinogenics is prohibited, several being cited above, there is one popular voice that some people used to listen to that goes to the contrary.

That would be Rabbi Zalman Schachter-Shalomi. He stated publicly that he personally consumed hallucinogenics and advocated for their usage in connection with religious experience. While he was living in the Germantown section of Philadelphia, he even composed and taught a blessing to be said before consumption.

http://www.yesodfoundation.org/Yesod-RZLP/Reb_Zalman.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zalman_Schachter-Shalomi

http://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-life-and-religion/167091/zalman-schachter-shalomi-december

https://scholarblogs.emory.edu/sacredmatters/2014/08/14/lsd-and-the-rabbis/

He is clearly in the minority, but it is worth noting that his view is out there.

Comment: I never heard of him.

Answer (score -2):

כִּ֣י | הַגּוֹיִ֣ם הָאֵ֗לֶּה אֲשֶׁ֤ר אַתָּה֙ יוֹרֵ֣שׁ אוֹתָ֔ם אֶל־מְעֹֽנְנִ֥ים וְאֶל־קֹֽסְמִ֖ים יִשְׁמָ֑עוּ וְאַתָּ֕ה לֹ֣א כֵ֔ן נָ֥תַן לְךָ֖ יְהֹוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֶֽיךָ:

Deutronomy 18 14

Other nations can have them, not us. "MAGIC" mushrooms, key word, magic.  Magic is a big no in Judaism. Therefore magic mushrooms are clearly not in theme with Judaism. Judaism rubs with "No such thing as coincidence" metric ergo it isnt just random chance they magic mushrooms aquired the magic prefix.

Comment: -1. By that logic, a Jewish physicist wouldn't be able to speak of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(physics)) as they relate to atomic theory. Nor would any Jew be allowed to visit Disneyworld's Magic Kingdom.

Comment: Did I write that we are not allowed to talk about magic mushrooms or consume them? We can speak about whatever we want stop giving me downvotes for no reason.