# Are there any halachic rulings on legal recreational marijuana?

Tags: posek-psak-decisor-ruling, intoxication

I have seen opinions from U.S. poskim from many years ago that rule that marijuana use should be forbidden by Jewish law on the basis of "dina d'Malchusa dina" ["the law of the land is the law"].  These rulings were made at a time when marijuana was universally illegal in the U.S.  Now that this situation is changing and recreational marijuana is becoming legal in state after state, have there been updated rulings either way?

If any posek rules that it should still be forbidden by Jewish law, even in a place where it is legal according to secular law, I would be curious to hear on what basis the posek distinguishes between recreational marijuana and "recreational alcohol".  And if they cite the concern that smoking may be a health risk, even for marijuana, would they allow food products containing marijuana?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10609. Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41153 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28325 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16341 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26517

Comment: Rav Moshe talks about that. Even absent medical concerns from smoke inhalation, marijuana does effect brain development and neurology, so you are harming your ability to think.

Comment: What is the logic of allowing alcohol but not marijuana?

Comment: @cliche retort.

Comment: If it's a cliche, it's only because it's a question that is hardly ever addressed.  It's the elephant in the room.

Comment: There is no evidence that marijuana affects the brain beyond the age of 25.  Alcohol on the other hand, damages just about every organ in the body, at every age and causes thousands of deaths a year from overdose, compared to zero marijuana overdoses.  These poskim would never dream of assuring alcohol and are extremely hesitant to assur tobacco, one of the deadliest substances used by humans