# Does any posek today permit smoking marijuana?

Tags: intoxication

Is there any posek alive today who allows smoking marijuana for recreational purposes?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55936/759 or further http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10609/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'd say that this is not a dupe, since it specifies "posek alive today who allows," a qualification that answers to the other questions may or may not address.

Comment: @IsaacMoses that was exactly my intention