# Is weed kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, tobacco-cig-smoking

Some says that qnei boshem in the bible, one of the ingredient of holy anointing oil is a plural form of qneibos or cannabis. Ganja.

Whether that's true or not, I sort of wonder.

Is it kosher?

It's legal in many states right. So it's okay to smoke weed?

Comment: I think most of the answer that doesn't address the kosher status of marijuana. It tries to say no you can't eat that using other reasoning.

Comment: Is beef kosher? Yes. Are you allowed to eat raw beefs or eat too much of it? Somebody will say it's against holiness of body bla bla bla bla. It's different things. Jews sound a lot like christians here. When something is politically incorrect somebody will come with a reason to say it's not allowed. So I asked a simpler question. Is it kosher?

Comment: If an answer that it is not kosher was available to the duplicate question it would have been used; it's an easier answer. The fact that the respondents  reached for different answers indicates that they could not say "it is not kosher".

Comment: Precisely. So there is some significant distinction between "allowed" and "kosher". Not simply because something is kosher means it's allowed or via versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a person with a doctor's prescription, marijuana is kosher and some marijuana derivatives have [recently been approved by the Orthodox Union](http://www.tabletmag.com/scroll/196294/orthodox-union-certifies-medical-marijuana-deems-its-use-a-mitzvah). For the question of use without a doctor approval, see [Is one allowed to smoke Marijuana?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10609/is-one-allowed-to-smoke-marijuana) .

Comment: I am asking whether it's kosher. Kosher and allowed may be different things. For example, the muslim consider pork to be halal if it's for medicine.

Comment: I mean to be permitted if it's for medicine but still not halal

Comment: @JimThio the word "kosher" means "fit".  I understand "halal" to be similar.

Comment: halal seems to mean clean. I thought kosher means clean too. Hmmmm... I do not know for sure actually. There is nothing in the bible that says thou shall not smoke weed.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67027