# Why does medical marijuana need a kosher supervision?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, medicine, hechsher-certification, marijuana

Today, NY State joined several others in opening clinics to dispense medical marijuana. Distribution of this is restricted to patients who have severe illnesses such as Parkinson's Disease, epilepsy, HIV, and IBS (Irritable bowel syndrome).

I understand that OU has issued its supervision on medical marijuana.

Is kosher supervision necessary on such a product? What non-kosher items could be mixed into the marijuana during processing?

Even if there were non-kosher substances, considering that a typical patient would be taking this to relieve or, perhaps, cure a serious medical condition, wouldn't it be permissible for someone to take this?

(My doctor recommends that I take fish pills that have non-kosher fish ingredients in it. He checked with his rav before recommending it, and I checked with my rav after he recommended it. Both agreed that for medical necessity, I was permitted to take it.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Rather than guessing, read it directly from the source.

> Some have also suggested that a natural product, derived from the
>   Cannabis plant, for a life-threatening condition, does not require
>   certification.  This is factually incorrect. The OU certified product
>   comes in three forms: pills, oils and vapor. While the cannabis plant
>   is inherently kosher, the final product may contain kosher sensitive
>   ingredients such as alcohol, gelatin and oil. The qualifying medical
>   conditions are not always life threatening, and even in such instances
>   where there is a threat to life, it is preferable to use a kosher
>   medication when available.
>
> The OU endorsed these products after careful review and consideration
>   by our distinguished Rabbinic consultants.
>
> The OU stands by its decision to certify medical marijuana products
>   that offer significant value to alleviate the suffering resulting from
>   serious and debilitating medical conditions. New York residents who
>   are experiencing intense pain, can now use OU supervised Vireo Health
>   medical marijuana and not be concerned that the product might contain
>   non-kosher ingredients.

Here's the link: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-news/ou-medical-marijuana-statement/

Comment: FYI the OU link now returns a 404 page not found. closest I could find is https://www.ou.org/news/vireo-health-new-york-medical-cannabis-ou-kosher/. the page did exist at one time. https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hQF2eB6hZGMJ:https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-news/ou-medical-marijuana-statement/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us