# Have there been notable Rabbinical opinions on hemp derived CBD oil for personal health?

Tags: halacha, medicine, health-safety-shmira, intoxication, drugs

Marijuana politics is getting complicated in the west with more and more countries legalizing the stuff for both medicinal and personal use.

**My question has less to do with Marijuana and more to do with its cousin hemp.** Hemp is an industrial/agricultural plant used for a variety of things in industry.

One of the more notable things about hemp is it produces a substance called CBD which is what is typically found paired with THC (the substance that gets you high in marijuana)

CBD doesn't have psychoactive effects. It doesn't produce the high that people get when they use marijuana and it has been found to help with a variety of medical conditions from seizures to Parkinson's symptoms and so on.

**My question:**

**Have there been any notable Rabbinical statements which attempted to differentiate CBD from Marijuana in terms of how the Rabbis define intoxicants vs medications?**

Do the Rabbis typically group everything into one category or have we reached a point where Rabbis have started to differentiate as new data on CBD comes out?

Comment: Medical marijuana ia considered to be medicine and is fully permitted by American and Israeli rabbis, the issue is kashrut supervision for products containing it. CBD oil should be no different.  See related:https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67027/why-does-medical-marijuana-need-a-kosher-supervision?r=SearchResults

Comment: I don’t get it. CBD is NOT a psychoactive element; how could anybody (rabbis included) suggest it’s an intoxicant?

Comment: @oliver gezeira atu marijuana maybe, in theory?  But no I don't see the question's motivation.

Comment: @Oliver This is another indication that G-d directs the entire universe. Literally today, I had a conversation with an individual who is using CBD (completely legally) for a medical condition. I have no personal experience with it, but took the opportunity to hear from a first hand source what the effects are. According to this person, there is a kind of very mild intoxication along with appetite stimulation and other effects.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that in terms of Torah, all plants, as long as they are not subject to orlah and Kilayim, are permitted for use/consumption. All the normal considerations, like is it a danger to life meaning poisonous or addictive, is there any insect infestation, etc. are relevant.

Comment: @YaacovDeane From personal experience (aside for the scientific observation and testing that already exists) I can share with you that there is no “mild intoxication” neither from oral consumption or otherwise. Perhaps the individual you conversed with was experiencing some placebo effect. The other considerations you mention in your second comment, while relevant, are not what OP asked about.

Comment: @Oliver I am not disputing your personal experience, but know that like with all drugs, impact and effect varies from one individual to the next depending upon body composition, particular genetics and many other factors. I wouldn’t doubt the account of the person I spoke with, discounting it to “placebo”.

Comment: @Oliver concerning your claim that CBD has no psychoactive element/effect is not accurate. Even though the current political climate is more friendly in many places in regard to this, it doesn’t change the chemistry. In material that I have read over the years from Merck and other sources, it doesn’t reflect your claim.

Comment: @YaacovDeane My claim, leaving personal experiences aside, is based on recent international research. By non-psychoactive, I mean unlike THC and unlike conventional psychoactive drugs. But leaving the chemistry aside too, I’m not aware of any clinical cases reporting a “high” or “intoxication” from CBD. So mi’mah nafshach: If we’re talking chemistry - I don’t see how a rabbi can suggest an independent “definition”; if we’re talking actual experiences, well, the proof is in the pudding.

Comment: @Oliver The definition of a psychoactive drug can be found here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoactive_drug.      What follows is a recent peer reviewed scientific report on the psychoactive effects of CBD. It is very different from the effects of THC, but nonetheless psychoactive.  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0920996415000638?via%3Dihub

Comment: @YaacovDeane it depends how far we want to take the concept of "psycoactive"...kohenim were forbidden from serving in the Beit HaMikdash after ingesting date honey.....}