# Are there sources that discuss the proper role of mood-‎altering substances?‎

Tags: halacha, mussar-ethics, health-safety-shmira, psych-mentalhealth, drugs

I am curious if there are any sources (halachic or hashkafic) that discuss the use of mood or personality altering substances.‎ From Caffeine or Chamomile tea all the way to psychiatric medication,‎ are they tools for serving Hashem,‎ or were we created a certain way and should focus our efforts on managing that reality using our own forces?‎

[Edit:‎ Specifically,‎ I'm curious about substances that make a person more functional and makes their perception of reality more accurate,‎ like substances with anti-‎anxiety properties for someone who is anxious,‎ as opposed to hallucinogens,‎ which are a different subject. Should we accept our personality extremities as G-‎d-given and work to direct them psychologically,‎ or do substances have a role to play in that management.]

Thanks!

Comment: partial duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26517/170 & https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104438/170

Comment: The fruits of Genosar in Berachot 44a seem to have had a mind-altering effect on Reish Lakish.

Comment: Do sources that mention Coffee qualify as using caffeine?

Comment: @Dov Sure,‎ same thing

Comment: @msh210 I see the similarity,‎ but instead of asking if there is validity to disrupting one's sense of ordinary reality with chemical substances,‎ I'm wondering whether there is validity to using substances that increase the accuracy of a person's sense of reality & functioning,‎ eg anxiety medication for someone anxious,‎ or caffeine for someone not able to function.‎ If someone takes a drug that makes them better at Torah study,‎ that seems like a pretty different question hashkafically. Maybe it is good,‎ like healthy eating,‎ or maybe it is changing one's G-‎d-‎given personality,‎ etc.‎

Comment: ...יין למרי נפש

Comment: @kouty Agreed, hence the obligation to drink wine on Yom Tov to induce the correct mood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment above about - "whether there is validity to using substances that increase the accuracy of a person's sense of reality & functioning,‎ eg anxiety medication for someone anxious,‎ or caffeine for someone not able to function.‎"

It writes in the [Mishnah Berurah 89:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.89.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the following:

> וטיי"א וקאפ"ע מותר לשתותו קודם תפלה כדי שיוכל לכוין דעתו ולהתפלל ובפרט בהמקומות שרגילין בהם ואין מתיישב הדעת בלתם
>
> *Tea and coffee are permitted to drink before prayer in order that one is able to concentrate / direct his thoughts and to pray, especially in places where it is customary to drink them and one can’t concentrate without them.*