# Use of Cannabis in Halacha

Tags: halacha, responsa

Are there any notable Teshuvos concerning the use of Cannabis except the famous one by Rabbi Moshe Feinstein זצ"ל?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10609/759

Comment: See Rabbi Yitzchak Zilberstein's Techumin 23 and Rabbi Shlomo Aviner's Sheilat Shlomo 4:264

Comment: If memory serves correctly, there is a Teshuvah from Rabbi David Luria, z"l discussing the permissibility of using cannabis oil during Passover. He says for Ashkenazi Jews, even though strictly speaking it is permissible in terms of it not being included as kitniyot, it is better to be stringent during Pesach and avoid using it. That suggests that use of cannabis oil outside of Passover is not any issue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Luria

Comment: I heard third-hand that a rov from Chicago asked Rav Chaim Kanievsky about marijuana and his answer was, "Zog America az s'iz der sam hamoves" - "Tell America that it's deadly poison"

Comment: @YaacovDeane what exactly does he mean by cannabis oil?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Cannabis oil in his context is the oil extracted from the cannabis plant, most likely the seeds (think like peanut oil or grapeseed oil, remember peanuts and peanut oil were used commonly for Pesach during Reb Moshe's life). But it can also be derived from other plant parts. Depending on how it was prepared, the oil would definitely have some percentage of THC in it. But to put this in context, cannabis prior to 1900 was generally available and used commonly in both the United States and Europe. There are even stories about what herb the Ba'al Shem Tov smoked in his pipe.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://hakirah.org/Vol30Galper.pdf) article quotes many sources who discuss cannabis, including Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach in Maadanei Shlomo (p. 148). Rav Yair Hoffman also [discusses](https://www.5tjt.com/medical-marijuana-and-halacha/) the question and includes Rav Chaim Kanievsky in Shaar HaTeshuvos (25).